# Passing Newline character as an argument within shell

Tags: bash, newline

The program takes single character as an argument.

```
./myprog <character>
```

How can i pass **\n** in the shell to the myprog ?

Comment: Tag the question with the specific shell implementation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easiest but not very pretty:

```
./myprog "
"
```

EDIT: Still easiest, but I forgot about it:

```
./myprog $'\n'
```

Another alternative:

```
./myprog ^M                  # not ^ and M, but the literal LF character
                             # in `bash`, obtained by Ctrl-V, Enter
```

Or, you can do what these programs do, and parse the argument yourself. If you say `./myprog "\n"`, your code will receive the two-character string `\n` as its first argument - look for such a sequence and translate it to a newline (e.g. by passing the argument through `printf` or equivalent in your language, or by regular expression substitution...).

Comment: ./myprog $(echo -e "\n")
./myprog $(printf "\n")
These two doesn't work in my bash but ./myprog "
" and ./myprog $'\n' works. thanks

Comment: @Amadan The ones with `$( )` won't work even with quotes, because that strips trailing newlines from the output it captures. Backticks won't work either, because they do the same thing.